# Comic from 1970’s/80’s with a spaceship named Celeste

Tags: story-identification, comics, spaceship

My kid was named Celeste by her dad. He said it was from a comic he read when he was a kid. It was the name of a spaceship. Now my kid is an adult and asking where it came from. Unfortunately, this is all I know and I never thought to ask before we lost him. Is there anyone who knows where this could have come from and any details of the comic?

Comment: Since the Mary Celeste was a ship that was famously found abandoned, with her crew never seen again, the name "Celeste" has been a popular one for doomed ships in fiction.

Comment: There are [multiple examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_and_Zoids#Plot:_Zoids_storyline) that it [could be](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/eagle-holiday-special-5-eagle-holiday-special-1987/4000-319516/). Is there anything else you know about it? Which country did he live in? Was he a subscriber to any particular comic? Does she have any siblings with unusual names? Can you ask his parents whether they know what comics he read (since they probably had to fund them)?

Comment: As this questions stands, it is too broad — it has too many possible answers. If you can remember any details that might narrow it down a bit, you can [edit] the question to add these.

Comment: He was born in 1972 in East Yorkshire uk